# Unable to apply gradle plugin

Tags: gradle, plugins

I am trying to apply Teamscale gradle plugin to my project.

I am using 17.0.0 version.

When I do
apply plugin: "com.teamscale"

It gives error
Plugin with I'd 'com.teamscale' not found

I just want to add Teamscale gradle plugin that's it.

Comment: Looks to me like that plugin doesn't go further back than version 22.0.0 whereas the latest is 32.3.1 (see https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.teamscale). I don't know the plugin, but are you sure you need to work with such an old version?